# Sort a dataframe of 1 row by values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a little problem with this code in R:

```
partdis <- as.data.frame(part[,2:7])[1,]
print(partdis)

       Residential Commerce Mining Agricultural Industrial  Others
Part T    23,14721  11,09565      0 4,775601   43,42984 17,5517

partdis <- structure(list(Residential = "23,14721", Commerce = "11,09565", 
    Mining = "0", Agricultural = "4,775601", Industrial = "43,42984", 
    Others = "17,5517"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "Part T")
```

I want to order the dataframe from the lowest value to the highest (or vice versa, either works) but i cannot do it with this

```
partdisor <- partdis[,order(partdis[,1:6], decreasing = 1)]
```

because it shows up this error message: Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

i know that i could bypass this by treating it as a matrix and not as a dataframe, but there has to be a better way to order the columns by 1 row value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data contains strange comma placement. Are you by chance in a country which uses the decimal comma?

If not, then this works:

```
df[, order(as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df[1,])))]
```

If yes, then you want this (at least to get it working on my computer)

```
df[, order(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", df[1,])))]
```

If I'm being honest though, keeping the data in this format is really bad practice, especially if there's only one row per dataframe. You're much better off making the data clean and long. Long data is easier to use and behind the scenes, R runs faster when working with long data:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(., ",") |> as.integer())) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  arrange(value)
```

Output:

```
  name           value
  <chr>          <int>
1 Mining             0
2 Others        175517
3 Commerce     1109565
4 Residential  2314721
5 Industrial   4342984
6 Agricultural 4775601
```

Comment: Yeah, sadly i'm working in a code that was made before i entered the organization and i was told to not change it that much.